# How can I manually download the Play Store APK from Google?

Tags: google-play-store, apk, xiaomi

I have a Xiaomi Mi Note that doesn't come installed with Play Store. I'd like to install an APK for it manually, but all resources I've found on the web require me to install a binary from untrusted sources (e.g., a Mediafile upload).

How can I download the Play Store APK directly from Google?

Comment: I would argue that this is not a dupe: The the linked question is regarding downloading raw APKs via the Play Store, I am trying to download the actual Play Store APK from Google.

Answer (score 1):

Google does not allow downloading the Play Store directly from the Play Store itself, unless its an update to an existing installation. What you can do however is:

1) Root your phone (Xiaomi warranty isn't voided by rooting)

2) Use an app like [Flashify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgollner.flashify&hl=en) or fastboot to flash a custom recovery (CWM or [TWRP](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24052804347760870)) ([Refer this guide](http://en.miui.com/thread-135019-1-1.html)).

3) Flash a compatible [GAPPs](http://redmi1s-india.blogspot.com/2015/08/gapps-for-miui67-and-for-kitkat-444.html) package, which includes the Play Store APK. You can get it that way.

Comment: I'm trying to find out the *official* source where Xiaomi states that warranty wouldn't be void if rooting or flashing is performed by the user. For e.g. [OnePlus has it clear on its site](https://oneplus.net/support/answer/will-rooting-or-unlocking-the-bootloader-void-my-warranty). I checked the warranty page of Xiaomi and couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: One of my friends owns a Redmi 1S,and his warranty card said that rooting is covered under warranty.